# Count number of rows until blank text in Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to write a VBScript which opens up an Excel file and counts all the rows in column A which have data in it. The counting part is what I am struggling with, as many built-in functions used in VBA do not work in VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel's `COUNTA()` worksheet function counts the number of non-blank cells in a range. Combine that with the VBA `Evaluate()` function to call `COUNTA()` and return the result to your script. Then, it becomes this easy:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Open "c:\path\to\your\workbook.xlsx"

WScript.Echo "Rows with data in column A = " & objExcel.Evaluate("=COUNTA(A:A)")
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the brute force method.  It will work (not elegantly or efficiently) but it'll get the job done for a reasonably sized file.

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook, nonBlankCount
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Application.Excel")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\File\Path\Workbookname.xlsx")

xlApp.Visible = True
xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
xlBook.Range("A1").Select
nonBlankCount = 0

Do Until xlBook.Activecell = vbNullString
    nonBlankCount = nonBlankCount + 1
    Activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Msgbox nonBlankCount
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

`WorksheetFunctions` are still accessible through the application object.
Try this (I am skipping the opening part):

```
dim app, ws, rng
set app = getobject(, "Excel.Application")
set ws = app.activeworkbook.worksheets(1)
set rng = app.Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(1))
msgbox app.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)
```

`CountA` will give you the number of non-empty cells in a given range.
(yet it will not stop on the first empty cell.)